# Successful consumption of a Azure Machine Learning API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, azure, machine-learning

Does anyone have good documentation of a successful implementation of the Azure ML studio API in a web app that's not ASP.net? I'd like to run on it with ruby on rails, but I guess I have to figure it out on my own.

Comment: If my answer helps, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a rest API call.  Look at this...

```
data =  {

    "Inputs": {

            "input1":
            {
                "ColumnNames": ["YearBuild", "City", "State", "HomeType", "TaxAssesmentYear", "LotSize", "HomeSize", "NumBedrooms"],
                "Values": [ [ "0", "Anchorage", "AK        ", "Apartment", "0", "0", "0", "0" ], [ "0", "Anchorage", "AK        ", "Apartment", "0", "0", "0", "0" ], ]
            },        },
        "GlobalParameters": {
}
}

body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))

url = 'https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/45aeb4d8283d4be6ae211592f5366af5/services/07ffeeb6fcb84f16bc62cdcf67fd95b3/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true'
api_key = 'abc123' # Replace this with the API key for the web service
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key)}

req = urllib2.Request(url, body, headers)
```

Give a shot at trying with the postman app in chrome first.  Setting your headers, just as above, your data goes in the post payload in the json format.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find Ruby code (not python)

```
      data = {
        'Inputs' => {
          'input1' => [
            {
              'weekday' => 1,
              'hour' => 2,
              'events' => 0 
            }
          ]
        },
        'GlobalParameters' => {}
      }
      body = data.to_json

      url = 'https://asiasoutheast.services.azureml.net/subscriptions/[tour stuff...]execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger'
      api_key = '[your api key]'
      headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': ('Bearer '+ api_key)}

      RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: url, payload: body, headers: headers)
```